# Filtering for strings in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I would like to implement some custom cmdlets that filter some object by name, and I would like to use wild-card enabled search like for common cmdlets ([Get-ChildItem](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx) and [Get-Process](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849832.aspx)).

How can I implement this kind of search? Are there some examples or even some reusable components? Any examples?

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, these types of cmdlets leverage the [WildcardPattern class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.wildcardpattern%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Here's an example of how to use it directly from the PowerShell prompt:

```
PS>$w = New-Object System.Management.Automation.WildcardPattern "*foo*"
PS>$w.IsMatch("foobar")
True
PS>$w.IsMatch("barbar")
False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own filter by piping a collection of objects to [Where-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849715.aspx) (or the short-form `?`).

For example, if you get a collection of file objects by doing `gci` (alias of Get-ChildItem), you can display only the ones that have the text `log` in them by doing this: `gci | ?{$_.name -match "log"}`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I would like to implement it within the cmdlet because I would like to filter data accessed in a database.

Comment: Some cmdlets have filters (gci -filter "query"), but the filters are based upon the provider (for gci, it would be the filesystem provider) and aren't actually defined within the cmdlets themselves.

Comment: What @SpellingD means is that you would use the value of $Filter directly on your database query (after sanitizing it of course!).