# Wildcard matching in Get-ChildItem in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to determine how wildcard matching is done in Get-ChildItem?

Various articles ([1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242482/powershell-filtering-for-strings#)) suggest that it is done through the [WildcardPattern class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.wildcardpattern%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I don’t think this is the case. For example, suppose you have a file in `C:\test\test2\testfile.txt`. Then `Get-ChildItem –Path “C:\*\testfile.txt”` will not find the file while `WildcardPattern::IsMatch` will. Wildcard `"*"` matching in Get-ChildItem seems to be on directory level: so `"\*\"` will never match more than one level, like `"\A\B\"`.

So if [WildcardPattern class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.wildcardpattern%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) isn't used, then what is?

Comment: it will, if you use -recurse

Comment: @Adil No, it will not...

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, it's using the WildcardPattern as you describe. However, the cmdlet `Get-ChildItem` limits it to the current directory (characters except `\`), so it won't conflict with the `-Recurse` switch that goes to unlimited levels.

Answer (score 0):

Either would work:

```
gci c:\test\*\testfile.txt
```

or

```
gci c:\*\testfile.txt -recurse
```

Example:

```
PS C:\temp\test2> dir


    Directory: C:\temp\test2


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---          4/4/2013  10:41 PM          0 testfile.txt


PS C:\temp\test2> cd \
PS C:\> gci c:\*\testfile.txt -recurse -ea SilentlyContinue


    Directory: C:\Temp\test2


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---          4/4/2013  10:41 PM          0 testfile.txt
```

Comment: This is incorrect. Please test before posting if you don't know for sure.

Comment: @davor Actually, I did test them before posting. However, a "\s" was gone during the formatting of the first example, which is based on asker's directory structure.

Comment: @adii `gci c:\test\*\testfile.txt` works as I stated in the question because `*` is limited to one directory level. `gci c:\*\testfile.txt -recurse` doesn't. The fact that it apparently works in your case makes it even more strange. Anyhow, the main question (i.e. what patternmatching is used) is still unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

With "C:\*\testfile.txt", the asterisk plays a role just for the first level directory (e.g test). The file you're looking for is not there and the output you get is expected. Add another asterisk for the second level and you'll get the desired output (e.g "C:\*\*\testfile.txt"). You can also add the Recurse switch to start searching from the current location, all the way downwards.